# Como ler um arquivo .kar em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu estou tentando ler um arquivo .kar e depois printar as letras na tela, como eu faria isso em Python3? Eu tentei usar o Karapython, porém ele não funciona em Python3, alguma ajuda?

Comment: Coloca o código e o erro na sua pergunta, assim a galera consegue te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Cara, valeu, mas eu já consegui. Importei um módulo e editei ele, o .Kar é feito com metaeventos \xff0 (exemplo), ai o programa le e printa na tela.

Comment: @ArnaldoBadin, seria bom você colocar sua solução na seção de respostas e marcar como a correta, para ajudar pessoas que tiverem o mesmo problema que você.